# I've been working for one year. Can I apply for grad school in CS in Canada?

Tags: masters, application

I planned that I could make myself money to continue education (by obtaining a master's degree), but what am I supposed to do to continue my education? It would be nice if it's going to be a part-time education and I don't have to attend to school all the time.

My candidate would be University of Toronto or McGill.

I looked at their homepage, and the application information describes undergrad for high school applicants, or application directly from undergrad students.

On top of that I am not Canadian citizen (but a resident). Is there any chance for me to restart my education?

Comment: *or application directly from undergrad students* - what part of the application, specifically, applies only to students direct from undergrad? It's not clear what the problem is, exactly.

Comment: @ff524 in short, i want to know how to apply grad school in Canada after working for 1 year. i have this concern because i have graduated from school so it's not quite typical.

Comment: ... and I want to know why you can't apply in the usual way.

Comment: @ff524 i am not sure. because i am not... typical? and that's full time isn't it?

Comment: Are you asking how to apply to a part time program (in which case, it's not clear why you couldn't apply in the usual way?)? Whether you can do a "normal" program part time? Whether these institutions have a part time program? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @ff524 can i apply a normal program as part time? if not, how to apply for a part time program in these universities, if any?

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://www.sgs.utoronto.ca/Documents/AdmissionsGuide2016.pdf for graduate program admissions, or just the undergraduate admissions that is linked directly from the home page?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to get in contact with a specific professor who is an active researcher in an area of CS in which you would like to complete a Masters degree. If you find a supervisor who is keen to advise you (which you will need, anyway), he/she can help you negotiate the university admission process.

However, be forewarned. Many professors receive a lot of unsolicited emails from candidate students and are unlikely to respond. You need to make it very clear from first contact why it would be in his/her interest to supervise you, in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to apply as a returning student.  You will be an asset to the program because of your work experience.  Make sure you read the application instructions carefully.

You can probably also take a class here and there as an unmatriculated student.  Alternatively you may be able to audit a class.

Comment: wow. that's a fantastically encouraging piece of information!

Comment: And make sure to contact the university with any specific questions that come up.  Happy studying!